# Password storing in Python

Tags: python, encryption, password-encryption

I am writing a script that sends emails using the smtplib. I want to store the username and password so that the user doesn't have to enter it every time and I've found many posts about it, but none to the point.
I don't think I need a database to store one username and password (encrypted), but I don't know where to go to.
I was skimming through passlib's documentation, but it seems to return only boolean values and I'd need the password and username.
Any ideas on how to store them?

Comment: In what context is this being used? Who would be entering the password where and how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the circumstances but for now I can recommend [keyring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring/5.3)

> The Python keyring lib provides a easy way to access the system
>   keyring service from python. It can be used in any application that
>   needs safe password storage.

You have to set the credentials once in the user account. The user gets access to the password. It's always best practice to have a service user. You will reach the operating systems level of security.